# Implicit curve/surface definition of a polynomial function that's rotated and translated

Tags: polynomials, surfaces, curves, change-of-basis, implicit-function

Supposing I have an $n^{th}$-order polynomial curve $$y = \sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^i$$ and an $n^{th}$-order polynomial surface $$z = \sum_{i,j\in\mathbb{Z}^+\!,\ i+j=n} c_{ij}x^iy^j.$$ Now suppose that in each case, I want to transform the graphs of the functions by first rotating each graph with a rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ (planar rotation about the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and rotation about some arbitrary axis through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and then translating by a displacement vector $\mathbf{d}$. How can I determine the implicit functions $C(x,y)$ and $S(x,y,z)$ such that the transformed curve and surface are defined by the zero level-sets $C(x,y)=0$ and $S(x,y,z)=0$, respectively?

$\textbf{Edit}$: if it's not convenient to do this for the general case of an $n^{th}$-order polynomial, I am particularly interested in the cases when $n=2$ and $n=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand $$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=R\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}+t$$

and plug in

$$y -\sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^i=0.$$

Now you have an implicit equation in $u,v$.

Similar in 3D.

Comment: Firstly, thanks so much for your prompt response. I somewhat understand this, but I am still a bit confused about the $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ 'coordinate systems'. Aren't $u$ and $v$ the parameters in the local coordinate system of the polynomial? I specifically would like to express the transformed implicit curve/surface in the $(x,y)$ (or $(x,y,z)$ for the surface) 'global' coordinate system.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to see that I've confused myself by using the $(x,y)$ coordinate system in my post to define the polynomials. In fact I should have used the $(u,v)$ coordinate system, and then an inverse transformation of what you've given above should do the trick.

Comment: @niran90: that's it. $u,v$ to avoid confusion with $x,y$.

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks again!